# Xamarin forms map. Traffic above polylines

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, maps

I'm working with **Xamarin.Forms (2.3.3.180) Map** and added many `polylines` on it. But when I turn on "`traffic`" its layer are above my lines. Error is on both Android and iOS systems. I have been tried to do something with custom renders but in vain.

If i added `customTileLayer` its also displayed over `polylines` and another Map elements.

Comment: How can i reorder layers?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: I have't found the way to find a solution. native maps have't field layers, only tile layers/

Answer (score 1):

> I have't found the way to find a solution. native maps have't field layers, only tile layers.

You're right, the `Traffic` can only be disabled/ enabled, we can't change its layer. I've tried to change the layer of `Polyline` by setting `polylineOptions.InvokeZIndex(3000);`, and tried to increase this Z index, but it doesn't help.

By checking the official dev documents of google map, I didn't find any thing useful for this issue either. So basically it's not xamarin's problem, this feature is for now not supported by Google map.

You can check the issue report here: [Bug: Traffic data is displayed above drawn shapes (polylines)](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6468).

I think what we can do here is either increasing the width of `Polyline` or disabling the `Traffic`. If you want to increase the width, you can for example code like this:

```
polylineOptions.InvokeWidth(30);
```